# Почему окончание не является суффиксом?

Tags: словообразование, семантика, морфология, части-речи, словоизменение

Пишут, что суффикс это словообразовательная морфема, а окончание словоизменительная, но ведь когда изменяют слово оно уже не является прежним, это ведь новое слово с каким-то другим смыслом. с такой точки зрения окончание является ведь суффиксом, верно?
кстати, а каким термином обозначают окончание в лингвистике, что это за аффикс?

Comment: Кто же так пишет и где? Добавьте ссылок. Окончание — это вполне себе суффикс, просто особенно продуктивный в некоторых языках.